# Is there a way I can check to see if the "go to page based on answer" is checked in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When using `.setChoices()` It looks for an array of created choices.   If it is a multiple choice question it can be formatted either `createChoice(value)` or `createChoice(value, navigationType)`.

When looking at a choice you put in something like:  `var cPage = chkItem.getChoices()[j].getGotoPage();` 
This will produce either the page object or a Null value.

The problem is when a question is set to "go to page based on answer" and they have not set a page for every entry, and left the default to continue it also reads it (in my case cPage), as null.   This means if I want to go through each choice to capture it, modify it, then push it back out to the question, it my ending Array that I push out consists of both Null and Objects, which produces an error.

My workaround for questions without pages is for the script to forcibly change the question to handle page navigation but set everyone to CONTINUE.

I would like to find a way to check if the question has "go to page based on answer" checked and if not then be able to create choices using just the value.

Comment: If forms had an `onEdit()` or `onChange()` trigger, you could check the status after every user choice, but the only triggers the forms have is **OPEN**, **TIME DRIVEN**, and **SUBMIT**.   You can add a custom menu, which can run a script at any time, but that depends on the user making that choice.  Your question seems like it's the same as this one:  [StackOverflow - Dynamically Edit Multiple Choice Opions Live in Google Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:   I need to check the first choice if it has a `PageNavigationType()`.   If it does then the box is checked.   If null then it is not checked.     I have not written the code to fully test this but the theory should work.   (I was checking against just the goToPage type which is why it didn't work before. )

```
    var choicecount = chkItem.getChoices().length-1;
  var hasNavType = chkItem.getChoices()[0].getPageNavigationType();  //if null

  for (var j = 0; j <= choicecount; ++j) {
    var cValue = chkItem.getChoices()[j].getValue();
    var cPage = chkItem.getChoices()[j].getGotoPage();
    var cNav = chkItem.getChoices()[j].getPageNavigationType();
    //        Logger.log(j+" "+cPage);
    if (cValue != reValues[0]){ 

      if (hasNavType == null){
        newChoices.push(chkItem.createChoice(cValue));  
      } else {

      if (cPage == null){
        newChoices.push(chkItem.createChoice(cValue,cNav));
      } else {
        newChoices.push(chkItem.createChoice(cValue,cPage)); 
      }

      }
    } 
  }
```