# How Google Form automatically choose the radio button depend on another pair which surveyee chose to have sum of 1a and 1b equal to 5

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am studying and doing the survey. My questionnaire is a Google Form, including 32 pair of grid questions. Each grid question contain 2 Rows (1a. and 1b.) and 6 scale score columns (radio button: 0 to 5).

[image]

The way to answer each grid question is the sum of the radio button of each rows have to be 5 such as:

If a surveyee press the radio button of 1a. rows as 0, 1b rows have to be 5 automatically and also other cases (1,4) (2,3) (3,2) (4,1) (5,0).

Here is my question: how can the Google Form automatically choose the radio button depend on another pair score which the surveyee choose to have sum of 1a and 1b equal to 5. To prevent the useless questionnaire.

Comment: You cannot change a Form while making selections because no information is passed to the sheet until it is submitted. Answer already exists here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18649165/2278429

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to change subsequent questions based on the answer from the current question?

If this is the case there's some pretty straightforward documentation for this here:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en

Comment: Dear William Cross,my question is not the same as your link. As the google support link is Show questions based on answers. For my problem, i want the form automatic show the answer in the radio scale base on the previous answer. Please see the link: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/wvI2Qyu2qpjGBRasFmIw14WCbxK6il1kJtk2F72trKX6WKVH1qfHPfoH_S0R4nHZZ_3_Y037RCJR_LHoHpqFV-ySjB6gOZcaV0tMer2HJwvNqq0_4l_EjWIXTVRiJMMEtVnMuA=s800 If in question1 user choose disagree, i want the form show agree in question2 automatically

Comment: @chotirot in that case I am not sure if this is possible I'm sorry. There might be some sort of advanced functions that I am not aware of but I have never seen this kind of function done before. Normally Google Forms wouldn't have "locked" elements, meaning even if it were possible a user could then change their answer to question 2. Apologies if this isn't of much help!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by breaking your form into sections and have the form branch to different sections based on the answer supplied in a previous section. Its a technique you should use sparingly as too much branching will result in a bloated form whose responses will be difficult to parse in a spreadsheet.