# Use numerical answer in Google Form to select row number in Google Sheets for dynamic text in Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I would like to use Google Forms to assign categories to a list of sources in Google Sheets. I want to use Google Forms in specific because I need to create a pipeline for a group of people that is not familiar with programming. Google Forms is easy to use while still leading to a highly standardized output that I can subsequently import into R and analyze. Furthermore, Google Forms provides a better display of large amounts of texts (around 200 words) than Google Sheets.

Ideally (and taking into account Google Forms' relatively limited functionality with regard to using answers to previous questions to dynamically show next questions), I'm looking for a structure that looks somewhat like this:

1. Question 1: Manually provide number of source that you want to categorize.
2. Use answer to Question 1 to **display** title source and description of source as text, which are pulled from a row in a Google Sheet that corresponds to the answer to Question 1.
3. n questions about the source that is displayed, which are always the same (thus static).
4. Submit form (and show option to submit another response).

The answers to the questions should be automatically written to a Google Sheet, with columns for each question and a new row for each submitted form (just like usually would happen for a Google Form).

Although I don't think the set-up is very difficult or sophisticated, I'm struggling with how to get this to work - definitely due to my inexperience with using Google Apps Script, and not knowing the exact limits of Google Forms' functionality.

**Questions**

If possible, how can I create one form (prob. using Google Apps Script) that performs step 1 to 4? If this is entirely impossible to use previous answers for subsequent answers in Google Forms, how can I create a form for step 1 (again prob. using Google Apps Script), which then automatically redirects people to a second form for step 2 to 4, based on the answer on the first form?

Comment: I think you will have a tough time using Google Forms for your needs. I would do it with a web app but there will be many different opinions on how to do it which why I voted to close this question. It’s not the kind of question we handle here.

Comment: Google Forms does not have dynamic capability. So it can’t go look up options when a user selects an option. You can programmatically update the form with your questions and then use jumping conditions to control flow. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your reactions! Based on your comments and comments on twitter (https://twitter.com/Lisette_dJH/status/1273208921487015937?s=20) I conclude that Google Forms indeed is not able to do what I want it to. Therefore I've decided to abandon the idea of using Google Forms for this and just use Google Sheets. With a bit more effort, it's possible to display and read larger chunks of texts in Google Sheets, and I can also constrain answer possibilities. Thanks for clearing this up, knowing that something is **impossible** is important as well!

Comment: @Lisette_dJH actually I want to inspire you a little with a couple of suggestions. It's not possible to dynamically change G Forms on the fly, but there can be a work around. First, I think you can automatically assemble a new G Form if your Spreadsheets gets changed. This can be potentially possible, but it's a bit tedious and not error-proof, so at the first glance it's better be avoided. If you just have a static sequence of questions that want to get into a G Form, then you can simply make rules inside the G Form to send respondents to further parts of the form based on previous answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically edit multiple choice options in live Google Form using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script)