# Dynamically Edit Multiple Choice Questions in Live Google Form with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am a teacher trying to create a registration system with Google Forms, Sheets, and App Script. I have tried using [THIS THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script) to figure out the App Script I need to automatically update choices based on form submissions.

The Google Form will include class choices for Block 1, Block 2, Block 3, etc. Students will choose a class for each block and then submit the form. The Apps Script will look at the response spreadsheet, see that Class 1 for Block 1 is full, then removes it from the list of possible choices. The next student goes to register, and their only option is Class 2.

Based on the linked thread (see above), I tried this code. It seemed to work for one question... or so I thought. I linked my Spreadsheet here and include the Code Snippet.

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mrh79XlB_EX6jkK_dOX9sVIwAxTImqS8X2dIfEE0Juw/edit?usp=sharing) -- Available Classes in "formMaker" Sheet. (if there's a better way to do this, please let me know)

Code:

```
function updateForm(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('1Mrh79XlB_EX6jkK_dOX9sVIwAxTImqS8X2dIfEE0Juw'); // Base form  
  // need to read what dates are available and which are taken
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dates = doc.getRange("FormMaker!A2:A").getValues(); //available options
  var taken_dates = doc.getRange("Form Responses 6!C2:C").getValues(); 
  // joining the taken dates into one string instead of an array to compare easier
  var taken_dates_string = taken_dates.join("|");

  var choice = [];
  // loop through our available dates
  for (d in dates){
  }
  var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST); // our form list items
  // assumption that first select list is the one you want to change
  // and we just rewrite all the options to ones that are free
  formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(choice); 
}
```

Comment: Your going to get a lot of nulls and the end of dates and taken_dates when you specify you ranges that way.  You can filter them out or use getLastRow() after the range string which will eliminate them.  I would use dates.forEach

Comment: You won't be able to do it in a live google form.

Comment: @Cooper - is there another way you could do this?

Comment: Make your own forms with html and javascript